# Кабинет разработчика google play

Tags: android, java

Почему  в кабинете разработчика прошло уже четыре дня а он до сих пор показывает статистику  только за 23 февраля
СТАТИСТИКА за период: 22 февр. 2015 г. - 23 февр. 2015 г.
но еще и страница самого приложения в маркете не правильно показывает и оценки которые оставляли не показываются а только оценки за первый день а за последние четыре дня не видно!
[image]

Comment: Статистика запаздывает, это нормально.

Comment: @nekaneka на четыре дня запаздывать и не показывает оценки, хотя их должно быть много, это нормально на четыре дня, и вопрос, если это нормально, интересно, почему гугл не делает это лучше, неужели настолько сложно это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это вопрос в к гуглу. Тут никто гуглом не управляет.